# Fabric deployment asks for passphrase and login password

Tags: ssh, fabric

I'm trying to deploy local code to server.

```
khophi:~$ fab deploy
[178.x.x.x] Executing task 'deploy'
[178.x.x.x] run: mkdir -p /home/s
[178.x.x.x] Passphrase for private key: 
[178.x.x.x] Login password for 'khophi':
```

I've tried the password I used for generating the ssh key. Not working. Plus, what login password is it referring to?

To log into server, I just

```
ssh root@178.x.x.x
```

and that's all, however, trying to deploy code, its asking me all sort of passwords I've not asked for.

During the fab deploy, there's a stage where I'll pull from github, however, I don't think it's reached that stage. I've tried my github passwords too. Doesn't work.

Please help.﻿

Comment: Are you able to log into this machine using said key and/or password outside of Fabric?

Comment: @Morgan Yes. I am able to. I login almost everyday.

Comment: are you using a file to authenticate yourself while logging in ?

Comment: @Harman nope, I'm not using a file to authenticate. Any hints on that?

Comment: when you try to ssh, can you directly login to the machine ?
If yes, do check that the usernames match in the code and the one you're using for ssh.

Comment: @Harman Okay will do that. Away from PC now. However o have removed the 'khophi' user so will have to create a matching user

Comment: What I see from the snippet above is that you're trying to ssh to "khophi" user using fabric. However, when you're doing so manually the call is made to root user.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from the snippet above is that you're trying to ssh to "khophi" user using fabric. However, when you're doing so manually the call is made to root user.

If you have pasword-less ssh setup for "root" user, you may login only to that user remotely without a password.